# Generic function implementing Interface

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to call a generic function which implements an interface with set of properties.

the code is as below:

```
public bool NeedsRenderAction<M, U>(M parent, U child)
            where M : IVrsnProps
            where U : IVrsnProps
        {
           return true;
        }
```

i am calling it the below way. From the razor view.

```
bool x = NeedsRenderAction<LayoutVrsn, WidgetVrsn>(Model.SPV, widget);
```

The call even doesn't hit the function.
It error's out:  There is no implicit reference conversion from 'layoutvrsn object' to 'IVrsnProps'

Any work around plz...............

Comment: Are LayoutVrsn and WidgetVrsn implements IVrsnProps?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the parameter you are passing `Model.SPV` doesn't implement the `IVrsnProps` interface and the generic constraint you defined on your function prevents you from executing it. Judging from the error message you are getting it looks like the `SPV` property is of type `object` which obviously has nothing to do with the `IVrsnProps` interface.

For this to work you should either remove this generic constraint or have your SPV property of the correct type:

```
public IVrsnProps SPV { get; set; }
```

Same stands true of course for your second parameter. You are passing some `widget` variable and for this to work this variable must be a type that implements the `IVrsnProps` interface as well.

Comment: but i had forced it to implement  IVrsnProps

Comment: Where did you do that? In the function? That's the generic constraint. A generic constraint means that you need to pass a variable which satisfies this constraint. That's how generics work. Generics ensure compile-time safety meaning that your code will not compile if it is not guaranteed that you will pass the correct type. In your case you are passing `object` which could be absolutely anything at runtime. No guarantee at all. I would recommend you reading more about generics and how/when they should be used.

Comment: It worked on removing the constraint on it, but i must need the constraint. and setting SPV, i am already doing below stuff as SPV is also a generic..public T SPV { get; set; }    so u want me to override this or i can create another property that implements IVrsnProps

Comment: So if your SPV is delcared like this: `public T SPV { get; set; }` then you should add the same constraint to the `T` parameter on the containing class: `public class SomeModel<T> where T: IVrsnProps { public T SPV { get; set; } }`

Comment: I had already implemented an interface for that public class d2VwModel<T>
  where T : ISPV and when I try to implement multiple interfaces it errors out

Comment: But the generic type of the `SPV` property doesn't have this constraint. Where is this `T` coming from in your `public T SPV { get; set; }` declaration? That's where you should put the constraint.

Comment: It implements ISPV interface

Comment: Could you show your code. I don't understand how it implements this interface if you didn't specify it for the constraint.

Comment: public class d2VwModel<T>
  where T : ISPV
 {
  /*** Constructor(s) ***/
  public d2VwModel(PageBuildVrsn pbv, T spv, object vwdata = null)
  {
   PBV = pbv;
   SPV = spv;
   VwData = vwdata;
  }                                                              public PageBuildVrsn PBV { get; set; }
  public T SPV { get; set; }        
  public object VwData { get; set; }                      }                                                                       i will create object and use to make call to the function in my question. new d2VwModel<PgVrsn>(soup.PBV, pgVrsn, null)

Comment: In the code you have shown I see: `where T : ISPV` but in your `NeedsRenderAction` the constraint is defined as `where M : IVrsnProps` which is not the same thing. You need to have precisely the same constraint if you want to be able to invoke this method!

Comment: ok, thanks for your help, I had fixed that, the problem is that entities that i am having in the T type has to implement IVrsnProps.